# toggling visibility of div on click of a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have a navigation with list items containing "a" tags. One of the list item has a submenu which should be displayed on hover or click of the parent list item. How to toggle this using jquery?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far

Comment: read [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to toggle using jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On hover**

First in css you need to hide sub menu, like this

css

```
ul li ul{
    display:none;
}
```

js

```
$('ul li').hover(function(){
    $('ul',this).css('display','block');
},function(){
    $('ul',this).css('display','none');
});
```

`.hover(first parameter, [second parameter])` first parameter take mouse in and second take mouse out which is optional. For both parameters we have created anonymous function.

---

**on Click**

use toggleClass like this

js

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $('ul',this).toggleClass( 'showSubmenu');
});
```

css

```
.showSubmenu{
    display:block;
}
```

**Note**

You need to put class on ul or wrap ul in div with class and then target in jquery with that class otherwise it will be applied to all ul li on web page.

Comment: I have also updated code for click please check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going with `.click` as someone else gave you a way to get it working with hover. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v6X7x/1/

(take a look at the html in the fiddle)

Hide the second level menu items with css:

```
.layer2 {
    display: none;
}
```

And finally add a jQuery click event handler which first checks if there is a .layer2, then toggles if there is:

```
$(".layer1 li").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).find("ul.layer2").length;
    if (num > 0) {
        jQuery(this).children("ul.layer2").slideToggle();
    }
});
```

FYI: you'll probably get better answers if you put some of what you've already done in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/y924G/

The below code provides [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) events on the same `a`-tag as specified in the question.

JavaScript:

```
$dm = $('.dropdown-menu');
$('.dropdown').hover(
  function () {
    $dm.show();
  }, function () {
    $dm.hide();
}).click(function () {
    $dm.toggle();
});
$dm.hover(
  function () {
    $dm.show();
  }, function () {
    $dm.hide();
});
```